Is Trajectories of a system same for different initial conditions on the trajectories?
I have a system of differential equation $\frac{d\rm x}{dt}=f(\rm x, t)$, where $\text{x}\in A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t\geq 0$. The function $f$ is a smooth function. The set $A$ is the unit cube. I could able to show the system has an equilibrium point in the interior of $A$. Let $a\in A$ and $T_a=\{\text{x}(t, a):t\geq 0\}$ is the trajectory with respect to the initial condition $a$. If we take the initial condition from the path of the trajectories, do we get the same trajectory, i.e., If $b\in T_a$ it is true that $T_b\subset T_a$.
Is there any counter example for that. Does hypothesis of the problem important? Please give any hints how to approach this problem. Thank you!

It follows from the uniqueness theorem that the phase space trajectories of autonomous systems can never cross. So if you initialize your system at a point on $T_a$, it will follow the same trajectory.

But we do not know the whether the solution is unique.

Of course the Picard-Lindelöf theorem has to hold for the f(x,t) such that the solution is unique. This holds in most cases.
